# ExpandableListView dissapears after changing to other activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, expandablelistview

I'm using a ViewPager for the TabLayout with two Tabs. Both tabs contain a layout with an ExpandableListView. On first start of the app the ExpandableListViews shows correctly. But if i change to other Fragment and return  the ExpandableListViews dissapears.

I've searched a lot but found nothing similar except this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971035/list-view-dissapears-after-changing-activities).
But since i'm using databinding i don't use setContentView.

Here is the part of my current code.

**Fragment with ViewPager**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <!-- TabLayout with two Tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        />

    <!-- ViewPager for swipe -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter of the ViewPager**

```
   //Constructor to the class
public CategoriesPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    //Initializing tab count
    this.tabCount = tabCount;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //Returning the current tabs
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab_Income();
        case 1:
            return new Tab_Expense();
        default:
            return new Tab_Income();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.income_categories);
        case 1:
            return     context.getResources().getString(R.string.expense_categories);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Binding of First Tab** *The second tab contains same code just another list*

```
private FragmentIncomeCategoriesBinding binding;
CategoriesAdapter expandableListAdapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_income_categories, container, false);
    expandableListAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), GlobalLists.getInstance().getIncomeCategoriesMap());
    binding.expandableListViewIncome.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    return binding.getRoot();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    expandableListAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), GlobalLists.getInstance().getIncomeCategoriesMap());
    binding.expandableListViewIncome.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
}
```

**Layout of first ExpandableListView** *The second layout is the same code*

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView_expense"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
</layout>
```

**The Adapter for both ExpandableListViews**

```
 private Context context;
ArrayMap<Category, List<Category>> categoryMap ;

public CategoriesAdapter(Context context, ArrayMap<Category, List<Category>> categoryMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryMap = categoryMap;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return categoryMap.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return categoryMap.valueAt(listPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return categoryMap.valueAt(listPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return categoryMap.valueAt(listPosition).get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return categoryMap.valueAt(listPosition).get(expandedListPosition).getId();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CategoryListParentBinding parentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.category_list_parent, parent, false);
    parentBinding.setParentCategory(categoryMap.keyAt(listPosition));
    return parentBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CategoryListChildBinding childBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.category_list_child, parent, false);
        childBinding.setChildCategory(categoryMap.valueAt(listPosition).get(expandedListPosition));
    return childBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
```

I hope u guys can help because i have no idea what to do.

**UPDATE:**
i found the error and it was not in the code above. It was the way of starting the fragment containing the ViewPager.

The wrong call:

```
        CategoriesPagerAdapter adapter = new CategoriesPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            , 2, getActivity());
```

The right call:

```
        CategoriesPagerAdapter adapter = new CategoriesPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()
            , 2, getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by myself. If somebody have the same problem here is the solution.

Wrong call:

```
        CategoriesPagerAdapter adapter = new CategoriesPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            , 2, getActivity());
```

Right call:

```
        CategoriesPagerAdapter adapter = new CategoriesPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()
            , 2, getActivity());
```